# How to simplified the code using loop in shell script?

Tags: algorithm

I'm new to Shell Scripting and created the code below, but I need to simplify the code using a loop or something to make it shorter. When I tried to use the for loop in my code, I couldn't get the correct output, so I used an if-else statement.
So the program should prompt the user to enter 10 numbers, assign them equally to two arrays, and compare each element to the others.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a Array1
declare -a Array2

for ((i = 1; i<3; i++))
do
echo "(Array $i)"

for((j = 0; j<5; j++))
do

read -p "Enter number: " num

if [ $i == 1 ];
then
Array1[$j]="$num"
else
Array2[$j]="$num"
fi

done
done

echo "(Array 1) ${Array1[@]}"
echo "(Array 2) ${Array2[@]}"

arr11=${Array1[0]}
arr12=${Array1[1]}
arr13=${Array1[2]}
arr14=${Array1[3]}
arr15=${Array1[4]}

arr25=${Array2[0]}
arr24=${Array2[1]}
arr23=${Array2[2]}
arr22=${Array2[3]}
arr21=${Array2[4]}

if(( $arr11 > $arr21 ));then
echo "$arr11 > $arr21"
elif (( $arr11 < $arr21 ));then
echo "$arr11 < $arr21"
else
echo "$arr11 == $arr21"
fi

if(( $arr12 > $arr22 ));then
echo "$arr12 > $arr22"
elif (( $arr12 < $arr22 ));then
echo "$arr12 < $arr22"
else
echo "$arr12 == $arr22"
fi

if(( $arr13 > $arr23 ));then
echo "$arr13 > $arr23"
elif (( $arr13 < $arr23 ));then
echo "$arr13 < $arr23"
else
echo "$arr13 == $arr23"
fi

if(( $arr14 > $arr24 ));then
echo "$arr14 > $arr24"
elif (( $arr14 < $arr24 ));then
echo "$arr14 < $arr24"
else
echo "$arr14 == $arr24"
fi

if(( $arr15 > $arr25 ));then
echo "$arr15 > $arr25"
elif (( $arr15 < $arr25 ));then
echo "$arr15 < $arr25"
else
echo "$arr15 == $arr25"
fi
```

Comment: Why are you using i.e. `$arr14`, if you could use equally well `${Array1[3]}` in your code? Both names are equally "bad", as they don't tell us something about their semantics, so you can get rid of the unnecessary scalar variables (which already would make your code shorter).

Comment: Your question seems to be more targeted on finding a suitable simple algorithm and not of a concrete implementation in bash. May I suggest that you remove the _bash_ and _shell_ tags and use instead the tag _algorithm_. Also, when asking for help developing an algorithm, you certainly should write first a specification of what the program is supposed to do, instead of asking us for analyzing your code (which, even worse, does not contain any comments) to find out what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Please read the description of the tags you applied! As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use single for loop for the main processing in your code after you've taken the input from user. Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a Array1
declare -a Array2

for ((i = 1; i<3; i++))
do
echo "(Array $i)"

for((j = 0; j<5; j++))
do

read -p "Enter number: " num

if [ $i == 1 ];
then
Array1[$j]="$num"
else
Array2[$j]="$num"
fi

done
done

echo "(Array 1) ${Array1[@]}"
echo "(Array 2) ${Array2[@]}"

for ((j = 0; j<5; j++))
do
if(( Array1[$j] > Array2[4-$j] ));then
echo "${Array1[$j]} > ${Array2[4-$j]}"
elif (( Array1[$j] < Array2[4-$j] ));then
echo "${Array1[$j]} < ${Array2[4-$j]}"
else
echo "${Array1[$j]} = ${Array2[4-$j]}"
fi
done
```